# ¿Como hacer un POST de una variable y recibirla como objeto en PHP usando AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Practicando AJAX me surgio la siguiente duda:

Cuando queremos hacer un POST hacia PHP, colocamos en el atributo `data` del objeto AJAX, la variable que queremos que su contenido sea enviado.

Luego en el archivo PHP debemos hacer un POST de dicha variable.

Quise probar distintos valores y consegui esto:

**1) POST de una variable con un valor primitivo:**

```
$(function() {
        var variable ="victor";
        $.ajax({
            url:"cargar.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:variable,
            success: function(data) {},
            error: function() {}
        });
    });
});
```

**Codigo PHP**:

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";
    $data= $_POST["variable"];
    echo var_dump($data);
?>
```

> Retorna NULL

---

**2) Haciendo POST de un objeto**:

```
       var variable = {nombre:"victor",edad:22};
            $.ajax({
                url:"cargar.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:variable,
                success: function(){},
                error: function(){}
            });
        });
```

**Codigo PHP**:

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";
    $data1= $_POST["nombre"];
    $data2= $_POST["edad"];
    echo var_dump($data1);
    echo var_dump($data2);
?>
```

> Retorna Victor 22

---

**3) Haciendo POST de un objeto dentro de otro objeto**:

```
var variable = {variable: {nombre:"victor", apellido:"stack"}};

$.ajax({
        url:"cargar.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:variable,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#id").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#id").html("ERROR");
        }
    });
```

**Codigo PHP**:

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";
    $data= $_POST["variable"];
    echo var_dump($data);
?>
```

> Retorna array(2) { ["nombre"]=> string(6) "victor" ["apellido"]=>
>   string(5) "stack" }

---

**Mi pregunta es:** ¿De que manera debo hacer el envio de la variable para obtener un objeto como en el caso 3, pero sin tener que colocar dicho objeto dentro de otro?

**Ejemplo:**

```
AJAX >>> var variable = {nombre:"victor", apellido:"stack"};
PHP  >>> $_POST["variable"];
     >>> {nombre:"victor", apellido:"stack"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando varias (muchas) paginas encontré esta forma de hacer un `POST` del contenido de variable en su totalidad, y no unicamente tratarla como un array o en su defecto solo obtener los valores del `POST` de una llave:

**Codigo Javascript**:

```
// Pasamos el objeto , podemos usar "nombre" o nombre, igual funcionara
var dato = { 
    "nombre":"victor",
    "apellido":"alvarado",
    "edad":14
};

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"cargar.php",
    data: dato,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

**Codigo PHP**:

```
<?php
// Obtenemos todos los datos del POST, no únicamente del campo
$return = $_POST; 

// Luego eligiremos como deseamos trabajar el valor recibido:

// Forma 1, Array Asociativo:

foreach($return as $valor){
    echo $valor."<br>";
}


// Forma 2, Convertilo en JSON

$return= json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

De esta manera tendremos dos formas de recibir los datos:

**Forma 1**:

```
victor
alvarado
14
```

**Forma 2**:

```
"{\"nombre\":\"victor\",\"apellido\":\"alvarado\",\"edad\":\"14\"}"
```

Ahora bien si deseamos recibir con GET estos valores, no funcionaran para trabajarse como JSON a menos que: **codifiquemos el tipo de dato que se recibira**:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"cargar.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringfy(data));
    },
    error: function() {
    }
    });
```

Obteniendo esto:

```
{"nombre":"victor","apellido":"alvarado"}
```

Y para acceder a sus propiedades usamos ya sea `data.nombre` o `data.apellido`

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes tener presente es que AJAX sirve para transmitir información desde un recurso a otro, en forma de objeto pero simplificado a la notación de Javascript (JSON = `JavaScript Object Notation`). Por lo tanto, para utilizar JSON necesitas forzosamente crear un objeto con por lo menos una propiedad que será la que contenga el valor que quieres. La [notación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON) te exige tener un par `clave:valor` (`{clave: 'valor'}`) o utilizar un *arreglo* (`['Posición 0']`).

Por el otro lado, la misma estructura de PHP te indica que [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) recibe un arreglo, sea este *numérico indexado* (`$_POST[0]`) o un *[arreglo asociativo](http://www.anerbarrena.com/php-array-tipos-ejemplos-3876/)* (`$_POST["clave"]`).

Por lo tanto, la respuesta a tu pregunta

> ¿De que manera debo hacer el envio de la variable para obtener un objeto como en el caso 3, pero sin tener que colocar dicho objeto dentro de otro?

es: **no se puede**, si quieres recibir un objeto entonces debes enviar un objeto, la única variación podría ser:

```
JS   >> var variable = [{nombre: "Victor", apellido: "Stack"}]
PHP  >> $_POST[0]
```